# How to add the math expression title in multiple plots according to the column name of data set in R?

Tags: r, plot, title, symbolic-math

```
keep.beta
  beta_0 C1   beta_1 C1     beta_2 C1 beta_0 C2 beta_1 C2    beta_2 C2 beta_0 C3  beta_1 C3    beta_2 C3
1  6.118431  0.14186598 -8.898830e-04  6.022789 0.2284664 -0.008715484  6.362422  0.1623198 -0.007603638
2  6.063539  0.13401758  5.027927e-06  5.986915 0.2469357 -0.009225261  6.150559  0.2002901 -0.007515155
3  6.193407  0.05483201  6.126576e-03  5.841100 0.3347416 -0.016506298  7.146271 -0.3979893  0.041127363
4  6.078092  0.05110730  6.354140e-03  5.562972 0.4690519 -0.027162758  8.179671 -1.0250484  0.089065099
5  6.256228 -0.09785900  1.856215e-02  5.644385 0.4701571 -0.027528102  8.394842 -1.2646359  0.106934875
  beta_0 C4   beta_1 C4    beta_2 C4
1  6.097189  0.16624813 -0.004341827
2  6.164902  0.09360776  0.002282821
3  6.211754  0.03602315  0.007230330
4  6.505551 -0.10780312  0.016602683
5  6.692843 -0.24754950  0.028275593
```

To plot each column separately, I am using the following loop,

```
loop.vector=1:ncol(keep.beta)
  #plot for betas
  for(b in loop.vector) {
    x.beta<-keep.beta[,b]
    plot(x.beta, type = "l", main=colnames(keep.beta)[b], ylab="") 
    mtext("beta plot",line=-1.5, cex=1.5, outer = TRUE)
    }
```

All the title comes as `beta_0 C1` , `beta_1 C1` and so on. How can I replace all the betas in the title by math notation beta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need regular expressions to extract the betas and the Cs. Then use `bquote` with variables `.()` to plot them. This is similar to `expression()` but more flexible. And the `mtext` can go outside the loop.

```
op <- par(mfrow=c(2,3))
for(b in loop.vector) {
  x.beta <- keep.beta[,b]
  beta <- substr(sub("^beta_", '', names(keep.beta)[b]),1,2)
  Cn <- sub("^\\S+\\s+", '', names(keep.beta)[b] )
  plot(x.beta, type = "l", main=bquote(beta[.(beta)]~.(Cn)), ylab="") 
}
mtext("beta plot",line=-1.5, cex=1.5, outer = TRUE)
par(op)
```

[image]

**Data**:

```
keep.beta <- data.frame(1:5, 2:6, 3:7, 4:8, 5:9, 6:10)
names(keep.beta) <- c("beta_0 C1","beta_1 C1","beta_2 C1",
                      "beta_0 C2","beta_1 C2","beta_2 C2")
```

Comment: what if the column names are as `beta0_c1`, `beta1_c1` , `beta2_c1` and so on ?

Comment: Then replace the regular expressions in my answer to:  `nam <- names(keep.beta)[b] ;
  beta <- regmatches(nam, regexpr("\\d+", nam)) ;
  Cn <- sub('.+_', '', nam)`